# Pass the url into the parse method in scrapy that was consumed from RabbitMQ

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, rabbitmq, yield, pika

I am using the scrapy to consume the message(url) from the RabbitMQ,But When I use the yield to call the parse method passing my url as parameters .The program does not comes inside the callback method.Below is the foloowing code of my spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import pika
from scrapy import cmdline
import json

class MydeletespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Mydeletespider'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

def callback(self,ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    body=json.loads(body)
    url=body.get('url')
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)

def start_requests(self):
    cre = pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='10.0.12.103', port=5672, credentials=cre, socket_timeout=60))
    channel = connection.channel()



    channel.basic_consume(self.callback,
                          queue='Deletespider_Batch_Test',
                          no_ack=True)


    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()

def parse(self, response):
    print response.url
    pass

cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl Mydeletespider'.split())
```

My goal is to pass the url response to parse method

Comment: Could you finally solve this one?

Comment: No I could not.I have raised the issue in github

Comment: Can you help me to solve the issue'

Comment: I have raised the issue on the scrapy github repo, you can comment in there maybe help move it a bit :) https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3477

Comment: sure I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consume urls from rabbitmq you can take a look at [`scrapy-rabbitmq`](https://github.com/roycehaynes/scrapy-rabbitmq) package:

> Scrapy-rabbitmq is a tool that lets you feed and queue URLs from RabbitMQ via Scrapy spiders, using the Scrapy framework.

To enable it, set these values in your `settings.py`:

```
# Enables scheduling storing requests queue in rabbitmq.
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_rabbitmq.scheduler.Scheduler"
# Don't cleanup rabbitmq queues, allows to pause/resume crawls.
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True
# Schedule requests using a priority queue. (default)
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_rabbitmq.queue.SpiderQueue'
# RabbitMQ Queue to use to store requests
RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME = 'scrapy_queue'
# Provide host and port to RabbitMQ daemon
RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {'host': 'localhost', 'port': 6666}

# Bonus:
# Store scraped item in rabbitmq for post-processing.
# ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'scrapy_rabbitmq.pipelines.RabbitMQPipeline': 1
# }
```

And in your spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy_rabbitmq.spiders import RabbitMQMixin

class RabbitSpider(RabbitMQMixin, Spider):
    name = 'rabbitspider'

    def parse(self, response):
        # mixin will take urls from rabbit queue by itself
        pass
```

Comment: Thank for the update .I have tried out this .I am getting error in connecting to the rabbitmq Since the package does not provide any support for the Remote RabbitMQ connection with user name and passord

Comment: The package supports username and password connection, just add it to `RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {"credentials":  pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test'), ...}`

Comment: I have tried out `RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {"credentials": pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test'),'host': '10.0.12.103', 'port': 5672}
`  But I am getting the error  `'asyncore': pika.AsyncoreConnection,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AsyncoreConnection'
`

Comment: @JebaseelanRavi could you post full traceback to pastebin of sorts or open new question and paste it there? I've never seen this error before :)

Comment: I have opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763064/asyncore-pika-asyncoreconnection-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attri

Answer (score 0):

refer to this : http://30daydo.com/article/512

def start_requests(self) this function should return a generator, else scrapy wont work.