# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AsyncoreConnection'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, rabbitmq, pika

I am using `scrapy-rabbitmq` to fetch the url from RabbitMQ into my scrapy.I am using the following in my `settings.py` file

```
RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {"credentials": pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test'),'host': '10.0.12.103', 'port': 5672}
```

But I am unable  to connect to the rabbitmq .I am getting the foloowing error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AsyncoreConnection'
```

I have asked a another question that how to consume the data from RabbitmQ using scrapy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732711/pass-the-url-into-the-parse-method-in-scrapy-that-was-consumed-from-rabbitmq)

Comment: can you post _full_ traceback for the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment this line on its source code (connection.py).

```
    connection = {
    'blocking': pika.BlockingConnection,
    #'asyncore': pika.AsyncoreConnection,
    #'libev': pika.LibevConnection,
    'select': pika.SelectConnection,
    #'tornado': pika.TornadoConnection,
    #'twisted': pika.TwistedConnection
}[connection_type](pika.ConnectionParameters(**connection_parameters))
```